# Проверка пароля при вводе в TextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть TextField в который я ввожу пароль. После добавления нового символа мне необходимо проверять соответствие пароля некоторым требованиям (например 8 символов). Как можно этого добиться?
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 Задаете тип Connection - `Action`, Type - `UITextField`, Event - `Editing Changed`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 Проверяете что необходимо. 
К примеру, длина введенного текста 8 и больше символов:

```
@IBAction func myTfToCheck(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if let text = sender.text {
        let textLength = text.characters.count
        if  textLength > 7 {
            //Do something
            print("\(text), length: \(textLength)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за отличный способ!

Comment: @VAndrJ самый простой способ - это заюзать уже написанное, а не изобретать велосипед, имхо!

Comment: @AlessandroDP а чем это не юзать уже написанное? Стандартная функция стандартного `UITextField`. Для простой проверки не нужны какие-то монстры.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать готовый валидатор, этот 
[TextFieldValidator](https://github.com/dhawaldawar/TextFieldValidator) для obj-c, но и под свифт аналогов тьма.

Множество настроек, подсказки юзеру, проверка на совпадение паролей и тд.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылка, тут есть все что вам надо )

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223407/max-length-uitextfield

Чуть не забыл, не забудьте прописать делегат в расширении класса - `UITextFieldDelegate`
и указать этот делегат своему TextField

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Пользуйся.