# Обработка текста в TextField в реальном времени в приложении и вывод количества символов (int) в TextLabel

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development, swift3

Добрый день! 
Собственно, я понимаю как это делать используя Touch Up Inside кнопки, но мне хотелось бы что бы приложение само считало (без клика. По факту изменения текста в textField,  каждый новый введенный или удаленный символ, и передавало бы количество в textLabel).

Comment: Если вам дали правильный ответ, не забывайте отмечать его галочкой напротив. Это будет полезно для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на эту тему + будет благодарность автору ответа в виде репутации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант (см также данный ответ [насчет проверки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570405/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2-textfield/570431)):

1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 Считаете что необходимо.

```
@IBAction func myTfToCheck(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if let text = sender.text {
        let textLength = text.characters.count
        // и здесь устанавливаете в label
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо о компетентнейший программист! С 3 раза разобрался. Все считает как хотел!

Comment: @ИгорьИванов принимайте ответ тогда :)